# Is "poor selectors" an okay expression?

Tags: meaning

> Geology journals are **poor selectors** of high-quality research papers.

I would like to know if "poor selectors" is a correct expression and what other better expressions there are. I could not find instances of this expression in NYT and WaPo so I suspect it is weird for natives. Thank you so much.

Comment: Where did you search for "poor selectors"? Did you find unrelated results or no results? (This question may be closed if you don't describe your research.)

Comment: I searched in New York Times and Washington Post. I think that they use excellent grammatical English.

Comment: Yes, those are two good sources. You could search many more through [Google News](https://news.google.com/), for example. Please include that information in your question, since that's where it belongs.

Comment: Done. I also use Google News but problem is it includes 1) foreign newspapers with poor English, and 2) American second-rate newspapers with worse grammar imo (writers are sometimes interns)

Comment: The cited usage is clumsy. Google Books has no written instances *any* type of journals being labeled "poor selectors" of anything. Primarily that's because journals are passive inanimate things, so they don't "choose to select" anything (the editors and contributors do that). Note that the *primary* use of "is a poor selector" is essentially just a somewhat affected alternative to "is a poor **indicator**" (meaning *You can't assume a paper is high quality just because it was published in a journal*). In *that* usage, the implied agent making selections is the *reader* (not the journal).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "poor selector(s)" is a valid expression and often used. Here is an example within a mathematics context:

> The disadvantage of this criterion is that it is a poor selector in the presence of noisy data and in the problem of medium- and long-range prediction (when the observations might be consecutive values in a time series). ([Stanley J. Farlow, "The GMDH Algorithm," in Stanley J. Farlow (ed.), *Self-Organizing Methods in Modeling*, Marcel Dekker, 1984, pg. 11](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Self_Organizing_Methods_in_Modeling/QmwJEAAAQBAJ?gbpv=1&dq=%22poor%20selector%22&pg=PA11))

Here is an example from a science context:

> However, ciprofloxacin and levofloxacin are potent selectors of hl-OXA resistance, whereas moxifloxacin is a poor selector. ([Q. Ashton Acton (ed.), *Quinolones: Advances in Research and Application: 2011 Edition*, ScholarlyEditions, 9 January 2012](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Quinolones_Advances_in_Research_and_Appl/WAp-BbnL_20C?gbpv=1&dq=%22poor%20selector%22&pg=PT26))

I don't know of any "better expressions", but you could easily replace "poor" with a word such as "inadequate". It is tougher to find a good replacement for "selector"; "identifier" and "indicator" (mentioned in a comment below) are similar, but I think that they change the meaning a bit. You could certainly reword the sentence, e.g.:

> One can not easily identify high-quality research papers by using geology journals.

---

Comment: Thanks. Do you have alternative expressions?

Comment: @solange You could always replace "poor" with a word such as "inadequate," but I can't think of a word that would easily replace "selector". (Words such as "identifier" wouldn't work well IMO.) You could reword the sentence, e.g.: "One can not easily identify high-quality research papers by using geology journals."

Comment: @MarcInManhattan: I'm sure the intended meaning, and thus the obvious alternative word, is *it's a poor **indicator***. But it should really be *[**Being published in**] journals is a poor indicator...* Using plain "journals" as the "subject" is a bit odd, imho.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks, I think the meaning of "indicator" is a bit different from that of "selector", but I'll edit my answer now and mention that.

Comment: I think both your cited usages would be better with ***indicator*** anyway. There's nothing in the full OED to justify that random switch to ***selector***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I believe that "selector" is more often used to suggest that one is selecting from multiple candidates, while "indicator" doesn't imply that.

Comment: I'm not a chemist or biologist. Perhaps antibiotics are called "selectors" for, say, "resistance" because if you grow bacteria in a culture medium laced with specific antibiotics, this *increases the percentage of surviving bacteria* that are resistant to whatever is of interest ("lab selection", as opposed to Darwin's "**natural** selection"). But that kind of meaning doesn't seem to relate to OP's "journals" context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree that if that connotation isn't needed, then "indicator" could be used just as easily as "selector".

Comment: I don't know what you're telling the OP then. In *his* context, I don't think it *is* a "valid expression". I accept that in a few *very* specialized contexts we might refer to various "environments" as "good / poor selectors". But that's not really relevant to the average non-Anglophone, or the OP here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I find "poor selector" to be idiomatic in OP's context, so we disagree on this.

Answer (score 2):

As @MarcInManhattan answer points out, **poor selectors** is a valid expression.

other expressions I can think of:

- "Geology journals are poor in selecting high-quality research papers."
- "Geology journals often do not select high-quality research papers."
- "Geology journals are bad at choosing high-quality research papers."